# Reverse a string using C and inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to reverse a string, "Hello bob " and then passing it to another string using C and inline assembly. I'm using Visual Studio C++, and the result is `"Dbob bob"`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char source[10] = "Hello bob";
    char dest[] = "";

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        source[i] = source[10-i-1];
    }

    __asm
    {
        lea   esi, source
        cld
        lodsb

        lea   edi, dest
        mov   eax, 0xFF
        stosb

        lea   edi, dest
        cld
        mov   ecx, length source
        mov   eax, 0x44
        rep   stosb


        lea   esi, source
        lea   edi, dest
        mov   ecx, length source
        cld
        rep movsb
    }

    printf("%s",source);
    printf("%s" ,"\n");
    printf("%s",dest);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the second part of the string before you get to it. You need to do a "full swap" (`a->temp; b->a; temp->b;`) . Instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    source[i] = source[10-i-1];
}
```

An easy fix would be to change it to

```
char dest[10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    dest[i] = source[10-i-1];
}
```

Looking at it another way, if you start with "Hello Bob", you get:

```
Hello Bob
        ^
bello Bob
       ^
bollo Bob
      ^
boBlo Bob
     ^
boB o Bob
    ^
boB o Bob
   ^ 
boB o Bob
  ^
boB o Bob
 ^
boB o Bob
^
```

I indicate the letter that gets copied each time... you can see what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

You are making this far more complicated than it has to be:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 11;
char source[SIZE] = "Hello Bob";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE / 2; ++i) // you only need to go to the halfway point
{
    // std::swap(source[i], source[SIZE - i - 1]);
    char temp = source[i];
    source[i] = source[SIZE - i - 1];
    source[SIZE - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

That will reverse the string in place.  If you want to do it to a different array:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 11;
char source[SIZE] = "Hello Bob";
char dest[SIZE] = {0};
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    dest[i] = source[SIZE - i - 1];
}
```